# get the position of a specific vertex in an After Effects shape

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions

Is it possible to get the position of a specific vertex of an After Effect shape ?

something like

```
var shape = parent.content("Shape 1").content("Path 1").path.value;
var vertexes = shape.vertices;
var startVertex = vertexes[0];

...

[x,y]
```

But this code does not work...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 2019 you can access a path of a shape or a mask like so:

```js
myShape = thisComp.layer("Shape Layer 1").content("Shape 1").content("Path 1").path;
```

The `path` property is an object containing collections of points, inTangents and outTangents. It has three methods for obtaining the vertex details, `points()` returns the vertices, and `inTangents()` and `outTangents()` return the tangent handle positions if they have any. Each method optionally takes a time parameter to specify what time the data is retrieved. e.g.:

```
myPoints = myShape.points(); //you can optionally specify the time, e.g. .point(t=123)
myPoints[0]

myInTangents = myShape.inTangents();
myInTangents[0]
```

In addition there are other methods for getting an arbitrary point on a path not at a vertex, and for finding out if the path is closed. It's a world of fun! Read the docs [here](http://expressions.aenhancers.com/path-property.html#pathproperty-points-t-time)

Comment: that is wonderful ! thanks.